# svnsync file not found error

Tags: svn, svnsync, subversion-edge

I am using the latest Subversion Edge on Windows 2012 and I am trying to synchronize a repository with svnsync. I've copied the original repository (apache subversion 1.5 on Debian) with svnadmin dump/load. Now I'm trying to sync the repository to a secondary server that also runs the latest subversion Edge on Windows 2012.

`c:\csvn\bin>svnsync synchronize https://svnsync.destination/svn/main.svn --username=svnsync --password=xxxxxxxx
svnsync: E160013: File not found: transaction '102673-2782', path '/Projects/Hardware/Engineering Changes'`
The path "/Projects/Hardware/Engineering Changes" is added in revision 102675
so 2 revisions after the revision with the error.

Does anyone knows how to solve/bypass this?